# Having Numeric data type and character data type in the same column of a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, types

I have a large data frame (570 rows by 200000 columns) in R.  For those of you that are familiar with PLINK, I am trying to create a PED file for a GWAS analysis.  Plink requires that each missing character be coded with a zero.  The non-missing values are "A", "T", "C", or "G".

So, for example, the data structure looks like this in the data frame.

```
           COL1     COL2 
     PT1    A        T      
     PT2    T        T     
     PT3    A        A
     PT4    A        T        
     PT5    0        0
     PT6    A        A 
     PT7    T        A
     PTn    T        T
```

When I run my file in Plink, I get an error.  I went back to check my file in R and found that the zeros were "character" types.  **Is it possible to have two different data types (numeric and character) in a given column in R?**  I've tried making the 0's a numeric type and keep the letters as character type, but it won't work.

Comment: when you export your file, you can probably use `quote=FALSE` and get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Assuming PT1..n indicates family id, and COL1 and COL2 refers to the genotypes of one snp in n number of patients, I am raising these questions. Did you remove the header row: COL1 and COL2 in your file? PLINK does not like headers while creating PED files. Did you get an error in plink when you perform assoc procedure or you get an error when you are trying to combine the columns in your question with individual id, paternal id, maternal id, sex and phenotype. These additional parameters are required for the ped file.

Comment: Hi Sathish - Yes I have removed the header row and also included the Family ID, Individual ID, Paternal ID, Maternal ID, Sex, and Phenotype before adding the genotypes.  I was just showing an example of what the genotypes (columns 7 and onward) should look like.  I got an error when I tried to create a binary PED file using this command: plink --file data --make-bed  --out data.  The error was: ERROR: Locus "rs1003076" has >2 alleles:
       individual 6 2 has genotype [ "A" "G" ]
       but we've already seen [ "0" ] and [ "A" ]

Answer (score 2):

I think Justin's advice will probably fix the problem you have with Plink, but wanting to answer your question in bold...

**Is it possible to have two different data types (numeric and character) in a given column in R?**

Not really, but in this particular scenario, when it is a discrete variable, kind of yes. In R you have the **factor** basic type, an enumerate in some other languages.

For example try this:

```
x = factor(c("0","A","C","G","T"),levels=c(0,"A","T","G","C"))
print(x)

[1] 0 A C G T
Levels: 0 A T G C
```

You can transform them back in integers (first level is 1 by default) and characters:

```
> as.integer(x)
[1] 1 2 5 4 3

> as.character(x)
[1] "0" "A" "C" "G" "T"
```

Now when you read a table with read.table you can indicate that all character types should be read as factor even those with quotes around them.

```
mydata = read.table("yourData.tsv",stringAsFactors=T);
```